# Prevent log-in for an Already logged-in user C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, permissions

I have a desktop C# application, several clients are connected into SQL server. Each user has an ID and Password. what do i want is to prevent an already logged-in user to log-in from another computer.

I have implemented it by updating a Field in the database **'UserLoggedIn'=true** at the login, and when the user logs out the Field Updated into **False**. But this solution is not optimal, in which if the system crashed or the computer shutdown unexpectedly, the value will stay 'UserLoggedIn'=True in the database and this user will never can log-in again to the system.

What is the optimal solution for that, and prevent an already logged-in user from logging-in from another computer?

Comment: It's usually better to reverse the logic and have a new login cause the existing session to be terminated. That lets users resolve crashes/shutdowns themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `true`, store a timestamp in the database. Make sure that you update it periodically while the user is logged in.

When they log in, allow them if it's not too new. That is: if you've seen them from another PC within the last (say) 30 seconds, then consider that session still live, and reject the new login.

This way, if their other PC crashes, the timestamp will not be updated, and will eventually expire.

The update frequency should be about twice the expiry timeout. For example, if you want a session expiry of 1 minute, you should update the timestamp every 30 seconds.

Comment: Or just have a manual process and/or an overnight cleanup job. Seems like an age old problem in a way ..

Comment: @Paul - The author would be better off using the built-in membership capabilities buit-into ASP.NET

Comment: @Ramhound -- it's a desktop application.

Comment: I added it beside the UsedLoggedIn field, so if the UserLoggedIn=True, then it checks the last active session. That was a good idea @RogerLipscombe :)

Comment: Oh, and you might want to store the PC name in there as well, which will allow you to log back in from the same PC without waiting for the session to time out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check if the user has already established a connection to the database using the following query

```
SELECT loginame as LoginName,program_name
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE db_name(dbid)='my_database'  and loginame='test_user'
```

If the number of records returned is greater than zero then you can assume that a user has already connected to the database from your application.

If you look at the [connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property in MSDN, you will find the following properties of interest. These 2 properties can be added to your existing connection string to further improve the filters that can be defined in the query above

- **Application Name** - The name of the application, or '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' if no application name is provided. **(=program_name in the table above)**
- **Workstation ID** - The name of the workstation connecting to SQL Server. **(=hostname in the table above )**

*I believe that this solution will work irrespective of crashes on the client side and does not require that you save the state in any table.*

Comment: This assumes that you hold the connection open when you're not using it. With connection pooling, this is probably done for you, but...

Comment: [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) would be a better choice for modern development, but either one requires that the user has VIEW SERVER STATE permission